# MCMCglmm Package: error : Error in inverseA: individuals appearing as dams but not in pedigree

Tags: r, matrix, package, matrix-inverse

I am trying to find the heritability of animals. When I use dummy data on the function, it works just fine but when I insert my data from the database, I get the following error:

> Error in inverseA(pedigree = pedigree, scale = scale, nodes = nodes) : 
>     individuals appearing as dams but not in pedigree

I have removed all animals who appear in the pedigree but do not have any phenotypic data, yet the error prevails.

**Pedigree and data:**
[image]

```
prior <- list(R = list(V = 1, nu = 0.002), G = list(G1 = list(V = 1, nu = 0.002), G2 = list(V = 1, nu = 0.002)))

heritmodel <- MCMCglmm(birthweight ~ 1, random = ~animal + year, family = "gaussian", prior = prior, pedigree = pedigree, data = data, nitt = 1e+05, burnin = 10000, thin = 10)
```

PS. the data file is very large, I am only entering the first ten animals of the dataset.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to the problem using `extend` function from geneticsped package. Extend the pedigree first and then use it within mcmcglmm

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same problem, and solved by using a different approach (since the `geneticsped` package seems to be outdated).

Be careful with the following you did: *"I have removed all animals who appear in the pedigree but do not have any phenotypic data"*. As might be removing some of these IDs MCMCglmm is missing.

For me this solved the problem. Also, make sure that the pedigree and data objects passed to the arguments with the same name are of `class dataframe`. Eg.

```
pedigree = data.frame(pedigree)
```

I was processing files with functions from the `tidyverse`, which return tibbles with `class "spec_tbl_df" "tbl_df" "tbl" "data.frame"`, and this lead to the same error posted above.