# Problems with animal model

Tags: r, model

I´m trying to adjust an animal model. I have my data frame of my pedigree

```
      animal dam sire
1     A1     A1  b1
2     A2     A2  b2
```

and my phenotype

```
      animal   TT
1     A1     48.1
2     A2     52.7
```

My model:

```
model <- MCMCglmm(TT ~ 1, random = ~animal, family = "gaussian",
                  prior = prior, pedigree = pedi, nodes="ALL", scale=TRUE,
                  data = phen, nitt = 100000,
                  burnin = 10000, thin = 10)
```

but I have this error

> Error in inverseA(pedigree = pedigree, scale = scale, nodes = nodes) :
> individuals appearing as dams but not in pedigree

I've tried to change the package but I couldn't find a solution

Could somebody help me to tell me how to fix that?
I already used extend by GeneticsPed and I tried Inverse(), but none of them has worked.

Comment: Do any of the answers to [this duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47979560/mcmcglmm-package-error-error-in-inversea-individuals-appearing-as-dams-but-n) help? Apparently the package [doesn't like tibbles](https://onunicornsandgenes.blog/2019/10/06/using-r-when-weird-errors-occur-in-packages-that-used-to-work-check-that-youre-not-feeding-them-a-tibble/).